# VBA: Find a DATE & TEXT values in Sheet 1 (2 separate columns) and paste entire row in Sheet 2

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, search

Search through Sheet1 if 2 conditions are meet:

Text prompt user `InputBox` for DATE (Column A) and the Letter "X" (Column V) is a constant. If both conditions are met then copy + paste entire row to Sheet2.

Here is what I have for integer search from previous work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Dim strsearch As String, lastline As Integer, tocopy As Integer

'find what date? find other value?
strsearch = CStr(InputBox("enter the string to search for"))
lastline = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastline
    For Each c In Range("A" & i & ":V" & i)
        If InStr(c.Text, strsearch) Then
            tocopy = 1
        End If
    Next c
    'Copy the current row
    If tocopy = 1 Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("MONTH_END").Rows(j)
        j = j + 2
    End If
tocopy = 0
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: where is the `InputBox` that the users enters the "Date" to look for ? it doesn't appeadr in the code you've added

Answer (score 0):

You've got the basics there Adam. So, assuming that the data on sheet 1 is contiguous (i.e. there aren't empty cells followed by more data, but that an empty cell is the end of the loop), and assumes the data sheet (sheet 1) is the active sheet, you would be looking at this:

```
StrSearch = CStr(InputBox("Enter the string to search for"))
j = Sheets("MONTH_END").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
     If InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, StrSearch) And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 22).Value = "A" Then
         ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("MONTH_END").Rows(j)
         j = Sheets("MONTH_END").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row         'recalculate J now that a row has been pasted in
     ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)) Then
         Exit For         ' The get-out clause of the loop
     End If
Next i
```

This method only needs 1 `For Each` since the 2nd value you're looking for is always in the same column (V, col 22) so there's no need to go through each column in the row checking for the value.

Comment: Thanks for the  quick response, however 2 items remain. It is getting there but data in column 22 is not contiguous. The "a" shows occasionally.

Comment: but needs to be copied regardless of user input

Comment: If the data isn't contiguous @DeadlyGryphon then just drop the 'ElseIf' statement to have the loop continue over empty rows/cells.

Comment: or are you saying that the E in column 22 is **not** a condition to be taken into account when copying the rows over? If not, then just remove the ' And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 22).Value = "E"' bit.

Comment: It will not continue loop...just copies one row on "MonthEnd"

Comment: @DeadlyGryphon can you post a sample of the data itself, and exactly what conditions are required for the code to copy the data from the main sheet to the "Month End" sheet?

Comment: Only looking at ColA & ColJ. User search input is month in ColA. If their input and the letter "A" shows up in ColJ then copy/paste in Months_End. Also all letter "A"'s in ColJ must go to Months_End.

Comment: @DeadlyGryphon - are the values in Col A always the last day of the month, or do they contain different dates (I can't tell because of the formatting applied in that column)? Have you tried debugging, stepping through the code to check **both** the value in Col A is definitely matching to the user input **and** the variable J is being recalculated on iteration? Remove the '     ElseIf IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)) Then
         Exit For' bit of the code and try debugging to see what is happening. From what I can see, the code should work as required so I'm intrigued as to why it is not.

Comment: the dates are always the first of the month (i.e. 01/01/2017) A&P sets format the way cells are displayed. I did remove the ' ElseIf and loop will not continue...i am puzzled as well?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code (use F8 whilst in the VBA routine) and see what is happening? Is it iterating through and stopping once it has copied a value? Is it looping through but only finding one matching value for some reason?

Comment: Looping through code it never hits line 154 & 155 (after the then).....I have tied multiple strings  in different cols. No change...

Comment: Hmm, if you add a Watch for 'Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row' and break when the value changes, it should tell you what row Excel is looping until on the ' For i = 1 to ...' Sounds like it may not be calculating the correct maximum limit of rows to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have working now..bloated but works..

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim i As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

'find what date? find other value?
endRow = 6000 ' of course it's best to retrieve the last used row number via a function
pasteRowIndex = 1

Sheets("COMBINED").Range("V3").Value = InputBox("Please Input Date = NOTE: 
Format MM/DD/YYYY")

For i = 1 To endRow 'Loop through COMBINED and search for your criteria

 If Sheets("COMBINED").Cells(i, 1).Value = Range("V3") Or Sheets("COMBINED").Cells(i, 10).Value = "A" Then 'Found

        'Copy the current row
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
        Sheets("MONTH_END").Select
        Rows(pasteRowIndex + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1


       'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
        Sheets("COMBINED").Select
   End If
Next i
    'Go Home
        Sheets("MONTH_END").Select
        Application.Goto Range("A1"), True
        ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(1, 1).Select
        Sheets("COMBINED").Select
        Application.Goto Range("A1"), True
        ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```